# Missing WS-Addressing elements in Soap header using WCF / .NET Compact Framework

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, wcf-security, windows-mobile-6

I'm required to use WS-Addressing/WS-Security in our WCF services. The services are called by a mobile device, Windows Mobile 6 / .NET Compact Frameowk 3.5.

I have just about everything working, but for some reason MessageID isn't getting included in my header, and it's listed as a requirement. The binding and client have Soap12WSAddressing10 specified. I'm getting this from transport level logging:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_3">http://tempuri.org/ISyncService/GetSchemaResponse</a:Action>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="28815cbc-7d07-45ea-9ce6-ce0a68a375f2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">7a63c3ec-5955-47fd-9af2-45211b839783</ActivityId>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-4fb4f460-8485-492b-9865-1b4b49c5c187-16">
      <u:Created>2011-10-24T22:09:53.182Z</u:Created>
      <u:Expires>2011-10-24T22:14:53.182Z</u:Expires>
    </u:Timestamp>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if the question is already answered. I am assuming you want to add the ws addressing header `MessageId` in your response. You could implement an `IDispatchMessageInspector` and in the `beforesendreply` function you could add a `MessageId` in the reply( I used VB.NET but C# should be equivalent):

```
Public Sub BeforeSendReply(ByRef reply As System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message, ByVal correlationState As Object) Implements IDispatchMessageInspector.BeforeSendReply
   reply.Headers.MessageId = New UniqueId(Guid.NewGuid())
End sub
```

In my case both the `MessageId` and the `To`-header were missing in my response while using `messageversion Soap11WSAddressing10 or Soap12WSAddressing10`. I managed to add the `MessageId` with the above code, but if I try to add the `To` header in the same way, the `To` header is never included when the response arrives at the client.